# Function shows correct value to return but somehow returns None when called in another function

Tags: python, function, tree

So I am making a tree structure where I go through a few of the Items from league of legends. The user can decide at each intersection what item he wants to have displayed and what attributes of that item. A desicion path could for example look like this:
"Tank" -> "Frozen Heart" -> "Stats" -> stats of the item get printed out.
The problem is I am searching trough lists to determine the item that relates to the user input for example:
['Tank', 'ADC', 'Bruiser', 'Support', 'Jungle'] -> input "T" so the tank path gets chosen.
The problem arrises when two items start with the same letter. I solved this edge case by simply calling the function recursively on itself in order to get the user to input the second letter. if they still match it gets the third and so on until there is only one item left in the return list, here is the code for that function:

```
    def filter_by_first_letter(self, list, letter, i = 0):
        if i == 0:
            new_list = self.return_value(list)
        else:
            new_list = list
        return_list = []
        for item in new_list:
            if item[i] == letter:
                return_list.append(item)
        if len(return_list) > 1:
            print()
            print("There is still more than one item, enter the second letter to proceed!")
            print()
            print(return_list)
            print()
            new_input = input("Your choice: ")
            self.filter_by_first_letter(return_list, new_input, i + 1)
        else:
            #if printed this shows the correct item at renturn_list[0]
            return return_list[0]
```

As stated in the code it shows the correct item when i print it out before the return statement!
But then when I call it in another function whose main obligation is to traverse the tree structure, it has return None. The code works flawlessly when the function is only called once tho.

```
    def traverse(self):
        if self.children_exists():
            print("To start enter the first letter of the category/item you want!")
            print(self.return_value(self.children))
            u_input = input("Your choice: ")
            #somehow here if I call it here it returns None, eventhough in my filter_by_
            #first_letter it shows the correct Item. For example (Spirit Visage)!
            print(self.filter_by_first_letter(self.children, u_input))
            node_value = self.get_node(self.filter_by_first_letter(self.children, u_input))
            if self.value != "Items" and input("Do you want to go up a level? If so enter y, else press any butten: ") == "y":
                print(self.children)
                self = self.parent
                self.traverse_upwards(self.children)
                self.traverse()
            node_value.traverse()
        else:
            print("Here is what you are looking for: ")
            print(self.return_value(self.children))
            if self.value != "Items" and input("Do you want to go up a level? If so enter y, else press any butten: ") == "y":
                print(self.children)
                self = self.parent
                self.traverse_upwards(self.children)
                self.traverse()
```

I even printed it out to check if it is a problem within my get_node function but it also shows None when printed before doing anything with it!

So my question is if anyone has any Idea on why this problem arrises and what I can do to fix it because I just don't undersstand how this is even possible.
Thank you in advance, here is the full code for refrence, there is also another file in which i print some stuff and call the tree.traverse(). Only those two function should matter tho!

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, value) -> None:
        self.value = value
        self.children = []
        self.parent = None
    
    def add_children(self, children):
        for element in children:
            new_node = TreeNode(element)
            self.children.append(new_node)
            new_node.parent = self
    
    def add_child(self,child):
        new_node = TreeNode(child)
        self.children.append(new_node)
        new_node.parent = self
    
    def class_list(self):
        return self.children
    
    def get_item_list(self, i):
        return self.children[i].children
    
    def get_properties(self, i, j):
        return self.children[i].children[j].children
    
    def get_stats(self, i, j):
        return self.children[i].children[j].children[0].children
    
    def get_passives(self, i, j):
        return self.children[i].children[j].children[1].children
    
    def get_actives(self, i, j):
        return self.children[i].children[j].children[2].children
    
    def children_exists(self):
        if len(self.children[0].children) > 0:
            return True
        return False
    
    def return_value(self, list):
        new_list = []
        for el in list:
            new_list.append(el.value)
        return new_list
    
    def filter_by_first_letter(self, list, letter, i = 0):
        if i == 0:
            new_list = self.return_value(list)
        else:
            new_list = list
        return_list = []
        for item in new_list:
            if item[i] == letter:
                return_list.append(item)
        if len(return_list) > 1:
            print()
            print("There is still more than one item, enter the second letter to proceed!")
            print()
            print(return_list)
            print()
            new_input = input("Your choice: ")
            self.filter_by_first_letter(return_list, new_input, i + 1)
        else:
            #if printed this shows the correct item at renturn_list[0]
            return return_list[0]
    
    def get_node(self, value):
        list = self.children         
        for element in list:
            if element.value == value:
                return element
    
    def traverse(self):
        if self.children_exists():
            print("To start enter the first letter of the category/item you want!")
            print(self.return_value(self.children))
            u_input = input("Your choice: ")
            #somehow here if I call it here it returns None, eventhough in my filter_by_
            #first_letter it shows the correct Item. For example (Spirit Visage)!
            print(self.filter_by_first_letter(self.children, u_input))
            node_value = self.get_node(self.filter_by_first_letter(self.children, u_input))
            if self.value != "Items" and input("Do you want to go up a level? If so enter y, else press any butten: ") == "y":
                print(self.children)
                self = self.parent
                self.traverse_upwards(self.children)
                self.traverse()
            node_value.traverse()
        else:
            print("Here is what you are looking for: ")
            print(self.return_value(self.children))
            if self.value != "Items" and input("Do you want to go up a level? If so enter y, else press any butten: ") == "y":
                print(self.children)
                self = self.parent
                self.traverse_upwards(self.children)
                self.traverse()
            
    
    def traverse_upwards(self, list):
        print("You went up a level!")
        return self.return_value(list)

        





tree = TreeNode("Items")
tree.add_children(["Tank", "ADC", "Bruiser", "Support", "Jungle"])
tree.children[0].add_children([
    "Sunfire Aegis",
    "Frozen Heart",
    "Thornmail",
    "Spirit Visage",
    "Dead Man's Plate",
    "Gargoyle Stoneplate",
    "Randuin's Omen",
    "Adaptive Helm",
    "Knight's Vow",
    "Bramble Vest"
])

tree.children[1].add_children([
    "Infinity Edge",
    "Essence Reaver",
    "Phantom Dancer",
    "Bloodthirster",
    "Stormrazor",
    "Lord Dominik's Regards",
    "Rapid Firecannon",
    "Guinsoo's Rageblade",
    "Mercurial Scimitar"
])

tree.children[2].add_children([
    "Trinity Force",
    "Black Cleaver",
    "Titanic Hydra",
    "Dead Man's Plate",
    "Spirit Visage",
    "Sterak's Gage",
    "Thornmail",
    "Guardian Angel",
    "Blade of the Ruined King"
]
)

tree.children[3].add_children([
    "Locket of the Iron Solari",
    "Redemption",
    "Mikael's Blessing",
    "Ardent Censer",
    "Knight's Vow",
    "Zeke's Convergence",
    "Shurelya's Battlesong",
    "Moonstone Renewer",
    "Staff of Flowing Water",
    "Imperial Mandate"
]
)

tree.children[4].add_children([
    "Sunfire Aegis",
    "Dead Man's Plate",
    "Turbo Chemtank",
    "Duskblade of Draktharr",
    "Sterak's Gage",
    "Spirit Visage",
    "Thornmail",
    "Guardian Angel",
    "Black Cleaver",
    "Goredrinker"
]
)

for el in tree.children:
    for element in el.children:
        element.add_children(["Stats", "Passive", "Active"])    

tank_item_stats = [
    "500 Health, 30 Armor, 30 Ability Haste",
    "100 Armor, 400 Mana, 20 Ability Haste",
    "80 Armor, 250 Health",
    "450 Health, 55 Magic Resistance, 10 Ability Haste",
    "400 Health, 50 Armor, 5% Movement Speed",
    "40 Armor, 40 Magic Resistance",
    "80 Armor, 250 Health, 20 Ability Haste",
    "350 Health, 55 Magic Resistance, 10 Ability Haste",
    "400 Health, 20 Armor, 10 Ability Haste",
    "35 Armor"
]

tank_item_passives = [
    "Immolate: Deal 26-43 (+1.5% bonus Health) magic damage per second to nearby enemies. Damaging Champions or Epic Monsters with this effect adds 100-160 (+10% bonus Attack Damage) bonus magic damage to the burn and immobilizes them for 1.5 seconds.",
    "Chill: Reduces the Attack Speed of nearby enemies by 15%.",
    "Thorns: Upon being hit by a basic attack, reflects 25 (+10% bonus Armor) magic damage, while also inflicting Grievous Wounds on the attacker for 3 seconds.",
    "Eternity: Increases all healing received by 30%.",
    "Carrion Renewal: Dealing or taking damage stores 60-100 (based on level) health, up to 100. Dying with over 100 stored health releases a shockwave, damaging nearby enemies for 100-200 (based on level) magic damage (10s cooldown, affected by Ability Haste).",
    "Stone Skin: Increases maximum Health by 100% and increases champion size, but reduces damage dealt by 60% for 4 seconds (90 second cooldown). Size and duration increase with additional Armor and Magic Resistance.",
    "Cold Steel: When hit by basic attacks, reduces the attacker's Attack Speed by 15% for 1 second.",
    "Diligent Defender: Taking damage from a spell or effect reduces all subsequent damage taken from that spell or effect by 15% for 5 seconds.",
    "Linked: While within 1000 units of each other, you and your linked ally heal for 12% of the damage dealt to champions by the other (increased to 15% on self).",
    "Thorns: Upon being hit by a basic attack, reflects 3 (+10% bonus Armor) magic damage, while also inflicting Grievous Wounds on the attacker for 3 seconds."
]

tank_item_actives = [
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "Vow: Designate an allied champion as your Partner (90 second cooldown).",
    ""
]

adc_item_stats = [
    "70 Attack Damage, 20% Critical Strike Chance",
    "55 Attack Damage, 20% Critical Strike Chance, 20 Ability Haste",
    "25 Attack Damage, 30% Attack Speed, 20% Critical Strike Chance",
    "55 Attack Damage, 20% Critical Strike Chance",
    "60 Attack Damage, 25% Attack Speed, 20% Critical Strike Chance",
    "35 Attack Damage",
    "30 Attack Damage, 35% Attack Speed, 20% Critical Strike Chance",
    "40 Attack Damage, 20% Critical Strike Chance, 20% Attack Speed",
    "30 Attack Damage, 20% Critical Strike Chance"
]

adc_item_passives = [
    "Critical strikes deal 225% damage instead of 200%.",
    "Echo: Critical strikes restore 3% of your maximum mana.",
    "Spectral Waltz: Ghost: Gain 7% Move Speed and ignore unit collision for 2 seconds whenever you deal damage to a champion (15s cooldown).",
    "Lifeline: When taking damage that would reduce your Health below 30%, gain a shield that absorbs up to 300-800 damage (based on level) for 3 seconds (90s cooldown).",
    "Energized: Moving and attacking generates Energize stacks. At 100 stacks, your next basic attack energizes you and deals 120 bonus magic damage to up to 4 targets (once per Energized effect).",
    "Giant Slayer: Deal up to 6% bonus physical damage to champions with greater maximum Health than you.",
    "Energized: Moving and attacking generates Energize stacks. At 100 stacks, your next basic attack gains 35% bonus range (+150 range maximum) and deals 120 bonus magic damage on hit (once per Energized effect).",
    "Phantom Hit: Every third basic attack triggers your on-hit effects an additional time.",
    "Quicksilver: Removes all crowd control debuffs and also grants +50% bonus Movement Speed for 1 second (90 second cooldown)."
]

adc_item_actives = [
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
]

bruiser_item_stats = [
    "450 Health, 30 Attack Damage",
    "30 Attack Damage, 30 Ability Haste, 200 Health, 25 Attack Speed",
    "40 Attack Damage, 400 Health, 20 Ability Haste",
    "500 Health, 30 Attack Damage, 30% Attack Speed",
    "400 Health, 40 Armor",
    "450 Health, 55 Magic Resistance, 100% Base Health Regen",
    "250 Health, 80 Armor",
    "40 Attack Damage, 45 Attack Damage, 40 Armor",
    "40 Attack Damage, 30 Attack Speed, 12% Life Steal"
]

bruiser_item_actives = [
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
]

bruiser_item_passives = [
    "Sterak's Fury: Lifeline effect grants a shield for 75% of your bonus Health (+30% bonus AD) for 8 seconds.",
    "Spellblade: After using an ability, your next basic attack within 10 seconds deals bonus physical damage equal to 200% of your base Attack Damage.",
    "Carve: Dealing physical damage to a target reduces their Armor by 4% for 6 seconds, stacking up to 6 times for a maximum of 24% Armor reduction.",
    "Cleave: Basic attacks deal 5 (+1% maximum Health) bonus physical damage to your target and 40 (+2.5% maximum Health) bonus physical damage to other enemies in a cone on-hit.",
    "Dreadnought: While moving, build stacks of Momentum, increasing movement speed by up to 60 at 100 stacks. Momentum quickly decays while not moving.",
    "Sorcery: Increases all healing received by 25%.",
    "Thorns: Upon being hit by a basic attack, reflects 25 (+10% bonus Armor) magic damage, while also inflicting Grievous Wounds on the attacker for 3 seconds.",
    "Lifeline: Upon taking lethal damage, restores you to 50% of your maximum Health and 30% of your maximum Mana after 4 seconds of stasis (300 second cooldown).",
    "Lifesteal: Basic attacks deal 12% of the target's current Health as bonus physical damage (max 60 vs. monsters)."
]

support_item_stats = [
    "30 Ability Power, 20 Armor, 300 Health",
    "150% Base Health Regen, 10 Ability Haste, 200 Health, 150% Base Mana Regen",
    "40 Ability Power, 20 Ability Haste, 50% Base Mana Regen, 200 Health",
    "20 Ability Power, 10 Ability Haste, 50% Base Mana Regen, 200 Health",
    "250 Health, 10 Ability Haste, 35 Armor",
    "50 Ability Power, 20 Armor, 250 Health, 15 Ability Haste",
    "250 Health, 20 Ability Power, 100% Base Health Regen, 150% Base Mana Regen",
    "100% Base Health Regen, 10 Ability Haste, 200 Health, 100% Base Mana Regen",
    "60 Ability Power, 20 Ability Haste, 200 Health, 100% Base Mana Regen",
    "20 Ability Power, 200 Health, 50% Base Mana Regen"
]

support_item_actives = [
    "Embrace: Active shield yourself and nearby allies for 230-385 (based on target's level) for 2.5 seconds (90 second cooldown).",
    "Salvation: Active instantly heals nearby allied champions for 180-360 Health (based on target's level) and grants them 20% bonus Movement Speed for 1.5 seconds (120 second cooldown).",
    "Harmonize: Active removes all immobilizing effects and grants the target 40% bonus Movement Speed for 2 seconds (180 second cooldown).",
    "Favor: Healing or shielding an ally grants them 20-35 bonus Attack Damage or Ability Power (based on level) for 6 seconds.",
    "Sacrifice: Active binds yourself to target ally, redirecting 15% of the damage they take to you and healing them for the redirected amount.",
    "Convergence: Active nearby allied champion begins charging up and, after 4 seconds, deals 50-100 bonus magic damage (based on level) and slows enemies by 30% for 2 seconds (120 second cooldown).",
    "Inspire: Active grants you and nearby allies 40% bonus Movement Speed for 4 seconds (90 second cooldown).",
    "Starlit Grace: Active heals the target ally champion for 60-90 (based on target's level) Health, increased by 60% of your bonus Health (2 second cooldown).",
    "Ebb and Flow: Active heals or shields yourself and up to 3 allies for 70-100 (based on target's level) Health or 45-70 (based on target's level) Shield, increased by 20% of your bonus Health and bonus Ability Power (2 second cooldown).",
    "Mandate: Active marks an enemy champion with a beam of starlight for 4 seconds. Damaging the marked champion with an ability or basic attack detonates the mark, dealing 60-100 bonus magic damage and granting you and your allies 20% bonus Movement Speed for 2 seconds (60 second cooldown)."
]

support_item_passives = [
    "Iron Aura: Grants nearby allied champions 5 Armor and 5 Magic Resist.",
    "Salvation: Heals and shields on allied champions increase their Armor and Magic Resist by 5% for 3 seconds.",
    "Hallowed Mist: Immobilizing an enemy champion causes nearby allied champions to gain 40% bonus Movement Speed over 2.5 seconds.",
    "Censor: Shielding or healing an ally grants them 15% bonus Attack Speed for 6 seconds.",
    "Vow: When your bound ally takes damage, you gain 15% of the damage they take (before mitigation) as bonus Movement Speed towards them for 2 seconds.",
    "Convergence: Nearby immobilizing effect makes your next basic attack against champions deal bonus magic damage and grant you 20% bonus Movement Speed for 2 seconds.",
    "Inspire: Grants yourself and nearby allies 40% bonus Movement Speed for 4 seconds after casting your ultimate.",
    "Starlit Grace: Heal and shield power is increased by 10% for each additional ally affected.",
    "Wave: Healing or shielding an ally grants you both 15% bonus Movement Speed for 1.5 seconds.",
    "Erosion: Dealing damage to enemy champions with your abilities or attacks detonates the Mandate mark, dealing bonus magic damage."
]

jungle_item_stats = [
    "500 Health, 15 Ability Haste, 30 Armor",
    "400 Health, 40 Armor",
    "350 Health, 75 Armor, 15 Ability Haste",
    "55 Attack Damage, 20 Ability Haste, 18 Lethality",
    "450 Health, 30 Attack Damage",
    "450 Health, 55 Magic Resistance, 100% Base Health Regen",
    "250 Health, 80 Armor",
    "40 Attack Damage, 45 Attack Damage, 40 Armor",
    "40 Attack Damage, 400 Health, 20 Ability Haste",
    "45 Attack Damage, 400 Health, 15 Ability Haste"
]

jungle_item_actives = [
    "Immolate: Deals 20-40 (+1% bonus Health) magic damage per second to nearby enemies. Damaging champions or epic monsters with this effect causes them to be Immolated for 3 seconds (15 second cooldown).",
    "Dreadnought: While moving, build stacks of Momentum, increasing movement speed by up to 60 at 100 stacks. Momentum quickly decays while not moving.",
    "Firestorm: Active unleashes a fiery wave, dealing 60-100 (+3% bonus Health) magic damage (60 second cooldown).",
    "Nightstalker: Passive grants 18 Lethality and damaging a champion with a basic attack deals an additional 60 (+30% bonus Attack Damage) physical damage on-hit (60 second cooldown).",
    "Sterak's Fury: Lifeline effect grants a shield for 75% of your bonus Health (+30% bonus AD) for 8 seconds.",
    "Sorcery: Increases all healing received by 25%.",
    "Thorns: Upon being hit by a basic attack, reflects 25 (+10% bonus Armor) magic damage, while also inflicting Grievous Wounds on the attacker for 3 seconds.",
    "Lifeline: Upon taking lethal damage, restores you to 50% of your maximum Health and 30% of your maximum Mana after 4 seconds of stasis (300 second cooldown).",
    "Carve: Dealing physical damage to a target reduces their Armor by 4% for 6 seconds, stacking up to 6 times for a maximum of 24% Armor reduction.",
    "Bloodlust: Active deals 110-150 (+30% bonus Attack Damage) physical damage to nearby enemies and heals for 20% of your missing Health (90 second cooldown)."
]

jungle_item_passives = [
    "Immolate: Deals 15 (+1% bonus Health) magic damage per second to nearby enemies. Damaging champions or epic monsters with this effect causes them to be Immolated for 3 seconds.",
    "Dreadnought: While moving, build stacks of Momentum, increasing movement speed by up to 60 at 100 stacks.",
    "Supercharged: Nearby enemy champions are slowed by 50% for 1 second when you gain maximum Momentum stacks.",
    "Nightstalker: Damaging a champion deals an additional 60 (+30% bonus Attack Damage) physical damage and grants you 20% bonus Movement Speed for 2 seconds.",
    "Sterak's Fury: Lifeline effect grants a shield for 75% of your bonus Health (+30% bonus AD) for 8 seconds.",
    "Sorcery: Increases all healing received by 25%.",
    "Thorns: Upon being hit by a basic attack, reflects magic damage equal to 25 (+10% bonus Armor), while also inflicting Grievous Wounds on the attacker for 3 seconds.",
    "Lifeline: Upon taking lethal damage, restores you to 50% of your maximum Health and 30% of your maximum Mana after 4 seconds of stasis.",
    "Carve: Dealing physical damage to a target reduces their Armor by 4% for 6 seconds, stacking up to 6 times for a maximum of 24% Armor reduction.",
    "Bloodlust: Damaging an enemy champion deals 60-100 bonus physical damage and heals you for 15% of your missing Health."
]


i = 0
for item in tree.get_item_list(0):
    item.children[0].add_child(tank_item_stats[i])
    item.children[1].add_child(tank_item_passives[i])
    item.children[2].add_child(tank_item_actives[i])
    i += 1

j = 0
for item in tree.get_item_list(1):
    item.children[0].add_child(adc_item_stats[j])
    item.children[1].add_child(adc_item_passives[j])
    item.children[2].add_child(adc_item_actives[j])
    j += 1

y = 0
for item in tree.get_item_list(2):
    item.children[0].add_child(bruiser_item_stats[y])
    item.children[1].add_child(bruiser_item_passives[y])
    item.children[2].add_child(bruiser_item_actives[y])
    y += 1

z = 0
for item in tree.get_item_list(3):
    item.children[0].add_child(support_item_stats[z])
    item.children[1].add_child(support_item_passives[z])
    item.children[2].add_child(support_item_actives[z])
    z += 1

a= 0
for item in tree.get_item_list(4):
    item.children[0].add_child(jungle_item_stats[a])
    item.children[1].add_child(jungle_item_passives[a])
    item.children[2].add_child(jungle_item_actives[a])
    a += 1
```

Comment: Change `self.filter_by_first_letter(...)` to `return self.filter_by_first_letter(...)`

Comment: Omg you are right, I am stupid! ty this solved it!